# How do Environment variables with different ports work in docker-compose mariadb?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

They have sent me to do an exercise in docker and I have no idea how to do it, I find myself super lost.

What is requested is the following:

> "Create a docker compose file that launches two Maria db databases, in 3 different environments "
>
> "Depending on the environment, they should run on 3 different ports:
>
> - Development: 3306
> - Production: 3307
> - Testing: 3308
>
> The environment should be sent as a parameter added to the command
> docker compose "
>
> The databases should be interconnected with each other
>
> and greater than this: "With the command:
> docker-compose docker-file --dev docker-compose docker-file --pre docker-compose docker-file --pro
>
> passing that parameter, in the first one I would run a production environment, in the other preproduction and in the other development
>
> In each environment there will be variables that change, such as the database port. "

Up to here is all the information that they have given me and everything that has been asked of me.

Could someone help me solve this ???

The only thing I managed to do was create the 2 databases, but I am missing the environment section, which is what I don't understand.

Code I have in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
   version: '3'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' 
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

  mariadb2:
     image: mariadb
     environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test2'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
     ports: 
      - 3305:3305
     volumes: 
      - ./mariadb2:/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a docker-compose you can add the enviroment parameters by a `.env` file. I think that is what they ment when they asked you to do the exercise.

The `.env` file is loaded by default when you launch the `docker-compose` but you can specify it.

You may like to read the documentation first so you can try things out https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
Although the part that I do not fully understand how to apply it is:
"With the command: docker-compose docker-file --dev docker-compose docker-file --pre docker-compose docker-file --pro"